# setting up graphQL on OpenShift

Tags: postgresql, openshift, graphql

I'm learning how to set up a server on OpenShift that uses node, express, GraphQL and Postgres and I need some help.

When trying to set up the GraphQL Server I've been following this and it works on my local machine:

```
import Express from 'express';
import GraphQL from 'express-graphql';
import Schema from './db/GQLschema';

const app = Express();

app.use('/graphql', GraphQL({
    schema: Schema,
    pretty: true,
    graphiql: true
}));
...
```

I'm using the server.js template provided by OpenShift so the above changes to:

```
...
self.app = express();

self.app.configure(function() {
    self.app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname+'/public'));
    self.app.use('/graphql', GraphQL({
       schema: Schema,
       pretty: true,
       graphiql: true
    }));
});
...
```

But this doesn't work when pushed up to OpenShift.  I get 'Internal Server Error' instead of the graphiql interface.

I'm new to this, but here are some guesses as to what it might have to do with:

1. Connecting to database
2. Missing dependencies

   1. Connecting to database:  I have 2 json config files.  One for my local machine which is connected using a port-forward SSH tunnel to OpenShift.  That works fine.  The other is one for production.  In it I have all the strings for the database name, user, port, host, and password, that OpenShift provided me.  I'm using the config library which looks at NODE_ENV to decide which config json file to use.  I set the NODE_ENV variable on OpenShift to production.  When I query it, it shows all the correct strings.  Is there something else I need to set?
   2. Missing dependencies:  To keep it neat, I am keeping my back-end code separate from my front-end code.  So the back-end code has only the express, graphql, sequelize, config, and pg stuff installed.  Do I need something else to make the graphiql page work?   Also, I put all the /node_modules/ in the .gitignore file -- I assumed that OpenShift installs them post push.  Was that the right thing to do?

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

OK - I solved it by doing the following:

in the openshift cli tools turn on error logs

```
rhc tail -a <yourappname>
```

This will give you some clues.  In my case it was a message from express-graphql "unresolved promise". After researching I found that if you install and save es-promise and add this line to the top of the server.js file:

```
require ('es6-promise').polyfill();
```

Hope that helps someone else!